# Plotly.js blocks UI while rendering large data set. Does it have any downsampling functionality?

Tags: ios, swift, plot, plotly.js

I am using **Plotly.js** to render a `histogram2dcontour` plot in a mobile application. The data is approx ~10^6 data points. It takes Plotly.js almost 3-4 seconds to render the plot. While plotting, the UI of the app hangs since the data is huge and plotting it is a blocking call. I understand that the data has too many points and this kind of behavior is expected.

Does **plotly.js** provide any functionality for downsampling huge data?
Or any effective downsampling techniques in Swift?

Any other suggestions are also welcome.